# PHP Closure returns an object

Tags: php, closures

Closures allow me to use for example:

```
$app->register('test', function() { return 'test closure'; });
echo $app->test();
```

Problem is, it's not working when the closure is returning an object. As in:

```
$app->register('router', function() { return new Router(); });
$app->router->map($url, $path);
```

I get: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Closure::map() in index.php on line 22`

```
/** app.php **/
class App {
    public function __construct(){
        $this->request = new Request();
        $this->response = new Response();
    }
    public function register($key, $instance){
        $this->$key = $instance;
    }
    public function __set($key, $val){
        $this->$key = $val;
    }
    public function __get($key){
        if($this->$key instanceof Closure){
            return $this->$key();
        }else return $this->$key;
    }
    public function __call($name, $args){
        $closure = $this->$name;
        call_user_func_array( $closure, $args ); // *
    }
}

/** router.php **/
class Router {
    public function map($url, $action){

    }  
}
```

Addon Details:

Does Work:

```
$app->register('router', new Router());
$app->router->map($url, $action);
```

but the purpose of returning an object in a closure is to provide last minute configuration as needed...I tried researching this, however most of the topics just describe how to call closures, which I already understand. That is why there is a __call method in the app class...

Edit:

```
$app->router()->map($url, $action);
Fatal error: Call to a member function map() on null in
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that a closure returns a Closure object, that's why it's different from the "Does work" version.

Also when you call

```
$app->router()
```

`__call` kicks in, not `__get`, so you get nothing since no callable router is defined in your class. I don't think there is a direct syntax to do what you want, you have to pass through a temp variable like:

```
$temp = $app->router;
$temp()->map($url, $action);
```

Comment: It actually is possible...in the `__call` method, I had to return the `call_user_func_array` call. Now, I can use: `$app->router()->map('url', 'action');` as desired...